# Ошибка git svn clone

Tags: git, svn

Добрый день
делаю

```
git svn clone -r74215:HEAD --username=usernmae --stdlayout --preserve-empty-dirs --authors-file=users.txt svn://svn.my.loc/pp .
```

> Процесс начинает идти и ломается, пишет: error: git-svn died of signal
>   11

Не как не могу побороть, может кто знает? Задча перевести проект с svn в git

Comment: гуглил `error: git-svn died of signal 11` ? какие решения не подошли? какая ос?

Comment: Обычно в логе источник ошибки в предыдущей строке. Покажите часть чуть больше лога

Comment: у меня 
`Distributor ID: LinuxMint
Description: Linux Mint 18 Sarah
Release: 18`


пробовал на другом компьютере
`Distributor ID: LinuxMint
Description: Linux Mint 17 Qiana
Release: 17`

на нем все работает, а на моем выбивает ошибку. Так что дело не в коде.

Comment: Пробовал разные версии perl 
`perl-5.18.2, perl-5.18.4, perl-5.24.0` 
не помогает, таже самая ошибка